# Referencing a created subnet and associate it with a given EIP for a NLB (aws provider)

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to parametrize the creation of a NLB, and provision in the same plan the necessary public subnets.

The subnets are specified as a variable of the plan:

```
variable "nlb_public_subnets" {
  type    = list(object({
    name              = string
    network_number    = number
    availability_zone = string
    elastic_ip        = string
  }))
  default = [
    {
      name              = "sftp_sub_A"
      network_number    = 1
      availability_zone = "eu-west-1a"
      elastic_ip        = "X.Y.Z.T"
    },
    {
      name              = "sftp_sub_B"
      network_number    = 2
      availability_zone = "eu-west-1b"
      elastic_ip        = "XX.YY.ZZ.TT"
    }
  ]
}
variable "common_tags" {
  description = "A map containing the common tags to apply to all resources"
  type        = map(string)
  default     = {}
}

locals {
  vpc_id = "dummy"
  base_cidr = "10.85.23.0/24"

  publicSubnets = { for s in var.nlb_public_subnets :
    s.name => {
      name              = s.name
      cidr_block        = cidrsubnet(var.base_public_subnet_cidr_block, 6, 
s.network_number )
      availability_zone = s.availability_zone
      elastic_ip        = s.elastic_ip
    }
  }
}
```

I'm specifying a name, a network number (to compute the cidr block), an availability zone, and an elastic IP to map to when creating the NLB.

Here I'm creating the subnets:

```
#Comment added after solution was given 
#This will result in a Map indexed by subnet.name provided in var.nlb_public_subnets
resource "aws_subnet" "sftp_nlb_subnets" {
  for_each          = { for subnet in local.publicSubnets :
    subnet.name => subnet
  }
  cidr_block        = each.value.cidr_block
  vpc_id            = local.vpc_id
  availability_zone = each.value.availability_zone
  tags              = {
    Name       = each.key
    Visibility = "public"
    Purpose    = "NLB"
  }
}
```

Now I need to create my NLB, and this is where I'm struggling on how to associate the freshly created subnets with the Elastic IP provided in the configuration:

```
resource "aws_lb" "sftp" {
  name = var.name
  internal = false
  load_balancer_type = "network"
  subnets = [for subnet in aws_subnet.sftp_nlb_subnets: subnet.id]
  enable_deletion_protection = true
  tags = merge(var.common_tags,{
    Name=var.name
  })

  dynamic "subnet_mapping" {
    for_each = aws_subnet.sftp_nlb_subnets
    content {
      subnet_id = subnet_mapping.value.id
      allocation_id = ????Help???
    }
  }
}
```

Could I somehow look up the configuration object with the help of the subnet name in the tags?

**UPDATE1**
Updated the dynamic block, as it had a typo.

**UPDATE2**
@tmatilai nailed the answer!

Here's the modified aws_lb block:

```
#
#This will result in a Map indexed by subnet.name provided in var.nlb_public_subnets
data "aws_eip" "nlb" {
  for_each  = local.publicSubnets
  public_ip = each.value.elastic_ip
}


resource "aws_lb" "sftp" {
  name                       = var.name
  internal                   = false
  load_balancer_type         = "network"
  subnets                    = [for subnet in aws_subnet.sftp_nlb_subnets : subnet.id]
  enable_deletion_protection = true
  tags                       = merge(var.common_tags, {
    Name = var.name
  })

  dynamic "subnet_mapping" {
    #subnet_mapping.key will contain subnet.name, so we can use it to access the Map data.aws_eip.nlb (also indexed by subnet.name) to get the eip allocation_id
    for_each = aws_subnet.sftp_nlb_subnets
    content {
      subnet_id     = subnet_mapping.value.id
      allocation_id = data.aws_eip.nlb[subnet_mapping.key].id
    }
  }
}
```

The trick is to realize that both `aws_subnet.sftp_nlb_subnets` and `data.aws_eip.nlb` are a Map, indexed by the key of `local.publicSubnets`. This allows us to use this common key (the subnet name) in the map `aws_subnet.sftp` to look up information in the data (`data.aws_eip.nlb`) obtained from the original input, `local.publicSubnets`.

Thanks. This is a neat trick.

Comment: Heads up that correct namespace is `subnet_mappings.value.id` and not `each.id`: https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks

Comment: Fixed, cheers @MattSchuchard

Comment: To work around this, unless someone has a solution, i have had to separate the plan into 2 different parts: one creating the subnets, and the other creating the LB, accepting the subnet_ids and elastic ips as input. Not pretty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing the IP address of the elastic IPs sounds strange. If you create the EIPs elsewhere, why not pass the (allocation) ID of them instead?

But with this setup, you can get the allocation ID with the [`aws_eip` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/eip):

```
data "aws_eip" "nlb" {
  for_each  = local.publicSubnets
  public_ip = each.value.elastic_ip
}

resource "aws_lb" "sftp" {
  # ...

  dynamic "subnet_mapping" {
    for_each = aws_subnet.sftp_nlb_subnets
    content {
      subnet_id     = subnet_mapping.value.id
      allocation_id = data.aws_eip.nlb[subnet_mapping.key].id
    }
  }
}
```

But maybe it would make more sense to create the EIPs also here. For example something like this:

```
resource "aws_eip" "nlb" {
  for_each = local.publicSubnets

  vpc = true
}

resource "aws_lb" "sftp" {
  # ...

  dynamic "subnet_mapping" {
    for_each = aws_subnet.sftp_nlb_subnets
    content {
      subnet_id     = subnet_mapping.value.id
      allocation_id = aws_eip.nlb[subnet_mapping.key].id
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. it seems that you are solving my issue, but I need to test it first :-)

Comment: I will answer your point about passing the EIP, and the other poitn about creating the EIP in the plan. 
So, I am passing an EIP instead of an allocation ID(and resolving the allocation_id with a data statement) , because to know the allocation Id, you need to have access to the AWS console in some capacity or other. I would like people (developers) to be able to use my plans having domain knowledge (the IP address) not system knowledge (the allocation id).

Comment: On the suggestion to create the EIP in the plan, this actually defeats the purpose (in our case) to be able to keep Elastic IPs stable and  to move the NLB from one VPC to the other. The Elastic IP is not part of the module.

Comment: It worked!!! Thanks so much. I still need to fix my dynamic block, as it is not correct. I'll update my question with the correct solution.